# Basic CSS Selector Logic

Tags: html, css

Learning CSS and having some problems with the logic of what I'm trying to select. I'm trying to make a global coupon style with two other classes that change the background color and font color. The black style is overriding the white style p fonts and can't understand why. 
Thanks for any help, Jacob
Here is the link to the HTML/CSS

[Live Coupon HTML Document](http://jacobnorwood.com/help/coupons.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Coupons Snippet</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

    </head>
    <body>


<div class="coupon white_c">
   <h3><span class="coupon_type_big">50%</span> Off CSS!</h3>
   <p>Present this coupon at checkout to receive half off your CSS order!</p>
   </div>


   <div class="coupon black_c">
   <h3><span class="coupon_type_big">50%</span> Off CSS!</h3>
   <p>Present this coupon at checkout to receive half off your CSS order!</p>
   </div>

    </body>
</html>


/*Coupon Style Sheet*/

 /*Global Coupon*/

.coupon {
   width: 250px;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   border: 3px dashed #ccc; 
}

.coupon h3 {
   font: bold 200% Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 1.3em
}

.coupon_type_big {
    font-size: 1.8em
}

 /*Coupon White*/
.white_c {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;

}

.white_c h3,p  {
    color: #000;
}

 /*Coupon Black*/
.black_c {
    background-color: #000;

}

.black_c h3,p  {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.white_c h3,p  {
    color: #000;
}

.black_c h3,p  {
    color: #fff;
}
```

needs to be:

```css
.white_c h3,
.white_c p  {
    color: #000;
}

.black_c h3,
.black_c p  {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Basically to make everything inside `.white_c` white, it's enough to use `.white_c { color: #fff; }`, no need to specify all the different elements inside it. Also, when you later on add (other) elements inside it, they will color white too.

Comment: That's true, but might not be what they want; I was just correcting the code they had and making it work.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Just some extra info for the TS, might be useful for her/ him. :)

Answer (score 2):

The comma in a CSS selector separates two selectors for which you want to apply the same rules, but each selector in the list is completely independent. So,

```
 .white_c h3,p  {
     color: #000;
 }
```

specifies that all p elements (as well as all h3 elements that are children of an element with the white_c class) should have black text. Similarly, the rule,

```
 .black_c h3,p  {
     color: #fff;
 }
```

gives all p elements white text, and since it comes later in the stylesheet, it overrides the previous color declaration for p elements.

I expect that what you are after is this:

```
 .white_c h3, .white_c p  {
     color: #000;
 }

 .black_c h3, .black_c p  {
     color: #fff;
 }
```